# Как доделать букмарклет для YouTube? Нужно сделать подсветку только тогда, когда значение больше определенного (просмотры на YouTube)

Tags: javascript, youtube

Как доделать букмарклет для YouTube? Нужно сделать подсветку только тогда, когда значение больше определенного (просмотры на YouTube)
**Код (букмарклет) почти готов для YouTube**

```
javascript:void((function()%7bvar%20a,b,c,d,e,f;f=new%20Array('pink','orange','yellow','aquamarine','lightskyblue','plum');for(a=1;a%3C=6;a++)%7bb=document.querySelectorAll('span.style-scope.ytd-grid-video-renderer:first-child');for(c=0;c%2Cb.length;c++)%7bd=b[c];[e=d.style](http://e=d.style);e.backgroundColor=f[a-1];e.border='solid 1px #00000000';e.padding='2px';e.marginRight='2px';e.color='black';d.innerHTML;%7d%7d%7d)())
```

Пример, как уже показывается, но нужно выводить только плашку для просмотров больше, чем допустим 2000
[image: Пример]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно собрать bookmarklet (на javascript), который можно будет использовать в браузере, как расширение (вкладка). Т.е. зайдя на канал пользователя, по нажатию на bookmarklet можно будет подсветить самые популярные видео таким образом

Comment: Вам стоит предоставить неминифицированный, читабельный код букмарклета —  с этим ребусом, увы, очень мало кто возьмётся разбираться.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать вариант без моего кода? Думаю и правда, там сложно будет его модифицировать

Comment: Пока не могу. Код-то ваш? Там ошибки синтаксиса (вроде `[e=d.style](http://e=d.style);`) и что-то малопонятное (вроде `for (c = 0; c , b.length; c++) {` или бессмысленного `d.innerHTML;`).

Comment: частично мой, частично код из открытого доступа, replace bookmarklet переписан)

Comment: Ну, что-то там явно не задалось при переделке, он не может работать в  таком виде.

Comment: Как я понял, реализовать можно примерно так, только собрать в единый код даже не могу
 javascript:void((function()
 let str = document.querySelectorAll('span.style-scope.ytd-grid-video-renderer:first-child#text'
 let regexp = /(.*?)k/g;
 let matchAll = str.matchAll(regexp);
 matchAll = Array.from(matchAll);
 matchAll%7bd=b[c];e=d.style;e.backgroundColor=f[a-1];e.border='solid 1px #00000000';e.padding='2px';e.marginRight='2px';e.color='black';d.innerHTML;%7d%7d%7d)())

Comment: Блок на странице с определенным стелем, делаем регулярное выражение на текст внутри блока и даём условие добавления стиля при числе просмотров больше какого-то числа

Answer (score 1):

В общем, написал bookmarklet для YouTube. Больше не актуально. К сожалению, **без сторонней помощи**)
Подходит для просмотров от 20к до 999к вроде. А после, на миллионы, уже другой юзаю

```
javascript:(function(){var count=0, text, regexp;text='^([2-9]\\d|\\d{3,})+K';if(text==null || text.length==0)return;try{regexp=new RegExp("(" + text +")", "i");}catch(er){alert("Unable to create regular expression using text '"+text+"'.\n\n"+er);return;}function searchWithinNode(node, re){var pos, skip, spannode, middlebit, endbit, middleclone;skip=0;if( node.nodeType==3 ){pos=node.data.search(re);if(pos>=0){spannode=document.createElement("SPAN");spannode.style.backgroundColor="yellow";middlebit=node.splitText(pos);endbit=middlebit.splitText(RegExp.$1.length);middleclone=middlebit.cloneNode(true);spannode.appendChild(middleclone);middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode,middlebit);++count;skip=1;}}else if( node.nodeType==1 && node.childNodes && node.tagName.toUpperCase()!="SCRIPT" && node.tagName.toUpperCase!="STYLE"){for (var child=0; child < node.childNodes.length; ++child){child=child+searchWithinNode(node.childNodes[child], re);}}return skip;}window.status="Searching for "+regexp+"...";searchWithinNode(document.body, regexp);window.status="Found "+count+" match"+(count==1?"":"es")+" for "+regexp+".";})();void((function()%7bvar a,b,c,d,e,f;f=new Array('#86ff86','#86ff86','#86ff86','aquamarine','lightskyblue','plum');for(a=1;a<=6;a++)%7bb=document.querySelectorAll('span.style-scope.ytd-grid-video-renderer:first-child > span,span.style-scope.ytd-video-meta-block:first-child > span');for(c=0;c%2Cb.length;c++)%7bd=b[c];e=d.style;e.backgroundColor=f[a-1];e.border='solid 1px #00000000';e.padding='2px';e.fontSize='18px';e.marginRight='2px';e.color='black';d.innerHTML;%7d%7d%7d)())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.